# Disable Pycharm print autocompletion

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2018.2 Professional edition.

I have an object with a `.print` method, but as I am typing `obj.print()` the first suggestion of Pycharm is to reformat as `print(obj)`.

How can I disable this code auto-completion (just the part relative to print)?

I tried to look in Settings and search for 'print', but with no luck.

Comment: Why not implement `__repr__` or `__str__` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to `Settings->Editor->General->Postfix Completion` and uncheck *print* from Python category.

[image: disable print]